# How can I use an Active Directory login in Microsoft Access linked to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, active-directory

We have a client who uses MS Access to manipulate data in their SQL Server DB. I know that we can set up SQL Server to authenticate using Active Directory. If we set this up, can they use their AD logins to connect to SQL Server through Access? How?

I tried Googling this, but to no avail. Any links or direction would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Also, please direct me to the correct place, if I should ask this question elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this should be pretty straight forward. You can use `Windows Authentication` to connect to sql server.

When establishing ODBC connection from your Client, The Wizard for connection configuration to SQL Server takes you to a page which gives you options to choose how you want to connect to SQL SERVER.  There you can choose to use Windows Authentication or SQL Server Authentication. You can choose the Windows Authentication Option.

Now when a client tries to connect to the SQL Server their windows credentials will be used to authenticate the user. And obviously if they are on a network their AD Account will Authenticate them.

See below a snapshot from `ODBC Data Source Administrator` wizard when configuring connection to sql server.

[image]

Comment: That was embarrassingly easy. Thank you

Comment: How could I do this on a workstation not using Active Directory? Any extra hoops to jump through to specify something different than the login information used for my machine?